# Create dropdown list of all the sheets in a google workbook

Tags: google-apps-script, dialog, google-sheets-api

I hope someone can point me in the right direction. I want to use google scripts to compare contents of 2 google sheets (one master and one with weekly information).  I would like the script to pop-up a dialog box with a dropdown control containing all the sheets in the workbook and using the control the user will identify the weekly sheet I want to compare against the master.  Probably need an OK button on the dialog.

I'd be happy to use the sidebar via HTML if this would work. I prefer the script be suspended, but can probably live either way.

I'm new to google scripts and could use some guidance. Is this even possible?

I found out how to popup an "alert", but I want a different control on the dialog.

```
function onOpen() {
  SpreadsheetApp.getUi() 
      .createMenu('Custom Menu')
      .addItem('Show prompt', 'showPrompt')
      .addToUi();
}

function showPrompt() {
  var ui = SpreadsheetApp.getUi(); 

  var result = ui.prompt(
      'Select the weekly sheet from the list below',
      ui.ButtonSet.OK_CANCEL);

  // Process the user's response.
  var button = result.getSelectedButton();
  var text = result.getResponseText();
  if (button == ui.Button.OK) {
    // User clicked "OK".
    Logger.log("OK");
  } else if (button == ui.Button.CANCEL) {
    Logger.log("CANCEL");
  } else if (button == ui.Button.CLOSE) {
    Logger.log("CANCEL");  }
}
```

Something like this:

[pop-up dialog with dropdown list](https://i.stack.imgur.com/YHPjK.jpg)

Comment: I have to apologize for my poor English skill. Unfortunately, I cannot imagine your expected situation from `I would like the script to pop-up a dialog box with a dropdown control containing all the sheets in the workbook and using the control the user will identify the weekly sheet I want to compare against the master. Probably need an OK button on the dialog.`. In order to correctly understand your question, can you provide the sample input and output situations you expect?

Comment: There already is one in your ui

Comment: Something like this: https://imgur.com/a/mbXpXHZ

Comment: "I want to use google scripts to compare contents of 2 google sheets (one master and one with weekly information)" This is a pretty common thing but you don't describe the nature of the comparison. So I wonder, why put the dropdown in a dialog box? why not put it in a cell in the sheet that will contain the comparison?

Comment: More detail of the problem: There is a golf competition called a ringer board.  It's a yearly competition that keeps track of the lowest score people get on all 18 holes. i.e. If I get a 3 on the 5th hole and my previous low score on that hole for the yea was a 4, then I record the 3 in MY ringer board.

Comment: Tedinoz.  Your solution would work. I was trying for a more elegant solution because I want to learn more scripting and this is for someone else who is not SW literate..

Answer (score 0):

After watching a lot more google scripts videos, it's apparent what I want is a web app that lists all the sheets in the workbook and updates the ringer sheet when one is selected.

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).